# Why is Actor.receive a partial function?

Tags: scala, akka

Why is `Actor.receive` a partial function? I can always have a regular function with match expression instead of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `PartialFunction` to capture the possibility of a message being handled or unhandled by the `Actor`. An unhandled message will

1. not make the Actor fail with a `MatchError`
2. spawn an `UnhandledMessage` event to the event stream

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Defining_an_Actor_class).

Answer (score 3):

One reason would be that the partial function has `isDefinedAt` method, which allows Akka to check if the message can be handled without catching the `scala.MatchError` exception from user's code.