# How does tell() work in Akka actor system?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am bit confused looking at the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.actor.Actor) and [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.actor.ActorRef)

`receive()` is a method which accepts no parameters and returns a Partial function. `tell()` is a method which returns `Unit` and it 'sends' the message. Now for the message to be processed in my understanding 2 things have to happen:

1. The `receive()` should be invoked by tell
2. The message is passed to the partial function which is returned by the `receive()`

Now if the partial function is returned back to the place where `tell()` was used, then how does message based communication work? Why isn't the operation being performed inside the actor itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is internals there is no documentation, but you can checkout source code yourself here: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala. All internals starting from how tell sends message to mailbox, how message is extracted from it, how receive is called and so on is here.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My question primarily was on the 'internal' working of tell rather than the big picture, especially in connection with why partial function is being 'returned' and why the message is not being processed 'inside' the actor itself.

Comment: @user567 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260676/why-is-actor-receive-a-partial-function hope it will help.

Comment: :) The linked question was also asked by me :) Anyway, these questions are different in their context